# Merge pandas dataframes based on value in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 and would like to merge them to a df3, based on the values in one of the columns, as shown below.

Please, how do I accomplish this?

df1:

```
+---+----+
|   | b  |
+---+----+
| 1 |  3 |
| 2 |  4 |
| 3 |  7 |
| 4 |  8 |
| 5 | 10 |
+---+----+
```

df2:

```
+---+-------+-----+
|   |   x   |  y  |
+---+-------+-----+
| 3 | True  | 5.4 |
| 3 | False | 6.9 |
| 4 | True  | 9.8 |
| 7 | True  | 7.8 |
| 8 | False | 5.6 |
+---+-------+-----+
```

df3:

```
+---+---+--------+-----+
|   | b | y_notx | y_x |
+---+---+--------+-----+
| 1 | 3 | 6.9    | 5.4 |
| 2 | 4 | NaN    | 9.8 |
| 3 | 7 | NaN    | 7.8 |
| 4 | 8 | 5.6    | NaN |
+---+---+--------+-----+
```

The code:

```
import pandas as pd

t1 = {'b': [3, 4, 7, 8, 10]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(t1, index=[1,2,3,4,5])


t2 = {'x' : [True, False, True, True, False],
     'y' : [5.4,6.9,9.8,7.8,5.6]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(t2, index=[3,3,4,7,8])

t3 = {'b': [3, 4, 7, 8],
      'y_x': [5.4, 9.8, 7.8, pd.np.nan],
      'y_notx': [6.9, pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, 5.6]}

df3 = pd.DataFrame(t3, index=[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Could you explain more on the operation used to get `df3`? The term `b` determines which index to look for under `df2` and returns and x True term under `y_x` and a x False term under `y_notx`. And the `b` column is determined by `df1`? Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! :-)

Comment: Very interesting question, thanks for posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need:

```
df4 = (df2.reset_index().pivot('index','x','y')
         .rename_axis('b')
         .reset_index()
         .merge(df1, on='b')
         .rename(columns={True:'y_x', False:'y_notx'}))
print (df4)
   b  y_notx  y_x
0  3     6.9  5.4
1  4     NaN  9.8
2  7     NaN  7.8
3  8     5.6  NaN
```

Explanation:

1. First [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) second `DataFrame`
2. [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by inner join (default)
3. rename boolean columns

EDIT:

Solution for multiple columns:

```
t1 = {'b': [3, 4, 7, 8, 10], 'c':range(5)}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(t1, index=[1,2,3,4,5])


t2 = {'x' : [True, False, True, True, False],
     'y' : [5.4,6.9,9.8,7.8,5.6],
      'v':np.arange(5) + 4.8,
      'w':np.arange(5) -2.75,
      'Z':np.arange(5) * 0.75  }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(t2, index=[3,3,4,7,8])

t3 = {'b': [3, 4, 7, 8],
      'y_x': [5.4, 9.8, 7.8, pd.np.nan],
      'y_notx': [6.9, pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, 5.6]}

df3 = pd.DataFrame(t3, index=[1, 2, 3, 4])

df4 = (df2.set_index('x', append=True)
          .unstack()
          .rename(columns={True:'_x', False:'_notx'})
          .rename_axis('b'))
df4.columns = df4.columns.map('_'.join)
df4 = df4.reset_index() .merge(df1, on='b')

print (df4)

   b  Z__notx  Z__x  v__notx  v__x  w__notx  w__x  y__notx  y__x  c
0  3     0.75  0.00      5.8   4.8    -1.75 -2.75      6.9   5.4  0
1  4      NaN  1.50      NaN   6.8      NaN -0.75      NaN   9.8  1
2  7      NaN  2.25      NaN   7.8      NaN  0.25      NaN   7.8  2
3  8     3.00   NaN      8.8   NaN     1.25   NaN      5.6   NaN  3
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly and I have marked it as an accepted answer. As a bonus though, could you find a solution that works if df1 and df2 had more columns? For example, if df1 had a column c next to b, and df2 hade columns v, w, z with arbritrary values -- how would you merge them in such a way that all information is kept but in an 'unstacked' way using suffices _x and _notx as the new column names.

Comment: @peternator - Give me some time.